# How to Join 3 tables based on 2 columns from one table in presto?

Tags: sql, join, presto

I Have 3 tables as below. In table1, if value in column id is present then join that column with other tables, if null I want to join with ref column from table 1 with other tables. What is the best way to do this

```
table1      
Name  id  ref
abc  123     
abc       456
edc  345  432
asd       678
```

```
table 2     
city    id  ref

NY     123  
WA          875
CA     345  432
SA          678
```

```
table 3     
city    orders  
NY      78954   
WA      123546  
CA      789 
SA      1
```

I want below result: ABC has 123 in id hence NY. ASD has 678, so considered ref column in table1 to join with other 2 tables

```
Name    city    order
ABC     NY      78954
EDC     CA      789
ASD     SA      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join`s for this purpose:

```
select t1.*, t3.city, t3.count
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id left join
     table2 t2r
     on t1.ref = t2.ref and t1.id is null left join
     table3 t3
     on t3.city = coalesce(t1.city, t2.city);
```

Note:  This returns all rows from `table1`, even those with no match in either column.  If this is an issue, add:

```
where t2.id is not null or t2.ref is not null
```